# What kind of script do I need to have a hidden div emerge from 2 divs in the center pushing one up and one down on hover

Tags: jquery, html, sliding

What kind of script do I need to have a hidden div emerge from 2 divs in the center pushing one up and one down on hover? I am not the best with jquery so I am not sure what I need to be searching for in terms of code.

I currently have a hidden text where on hover over the title the text appears but it leaves a long blank space for the text even though its hidden. I then made the header div smaller but when you would hover over it the text that appeared would then display over my button.

[What I'm looking to achieve (the 4 boxes of hover):](http://www.hsi.com/)

What I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/alexisdeals/7398hnbz/

```css
#text {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content:hover #text {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="test2" style="border:thin solid #aaa">
  <div style="float: left; text-align: center;" id="one">
    <div class="content" onMouseOver="show('text')" onMouseOut="hide('text')">
      <h3><a title="First Aid/CPR" href="#" style="color:#212121!important; font-weight:900;">First Aid/CPR</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p style="float: left; text-align: center;" id="text">Learn skills to save a life and receive a two-year certificate that meets American Heart Association standards.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="button" style="text-align:center">LEARN MORE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect you want from the website you gave I did some adjustments:

https://jsfiddle.net/ac0fh6qf/

I added vertical alignment for the content and some jQuery slide up/down for the animation. Also I removed the `float:left;` and the `visibility:hidden;` which I replaced by a `display:none;` which is more convenient.

Comment: Thank you! That was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You use `display: none;` `display: block;`, the `visible` property will hide the element but still take up the space that the hidden element will take.

https://jsfiddle.net/7398hnbz/1/

I also removed the `float: left;`, they have no reason being there. But you don't need javascript or jQuery for this task, it can be done with pure css.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

You just need to use `display:none` and `display:block` over there.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dejan.S said, you don't need JavaScript. Instead you can just transition some CSS property. Here's `font-size`.

```
#text {
  font-size: 0%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.content:hover #text {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

I also stripped out all of your inline styles in this Codepen: http://codepen.io/SteveClason/pen/wWaZgX

Answer (score 0):

- Create js file and invoke it and jQuery lib in yout  *.HTML  script
- customize your code as the following
- In js Script write this code

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $(".title").hover(
      function(){ 
          $(".middle").animate({
            height : '70px' , 
            fontSize : '18px'
            },600);

    } , 

    function(){ 
         $(".middle").animate({
              height : '0' ,
              fontSize : '0'
              },600);
      }
    );
  ```

  });

#### Html Script :

```
  <div id="test2" >

    <div class="title"> First Aid/CPR </div>

      <div class="middle"> 
               Learn skills to save a life and receive a 
                two-year certificate that meets American 
                Heart Association standards.

      </div>

        <div> learn More </div>

    </div>
```

#### Css Stylesheet :

```
#test2
{
    border:thin solid #aaa ; 
    text-align:center ; 
    margin-top:150px; 
    padding:30px;
}


.middle
   {
   height: 0 !important;
   line-height: 70px;
   color:red;
   font-size: 0;
   position: relative;

  }
```

and It Must work